# icloud backup storage issues

Tags: icloud, backup, ipod, camera

I'm not able to backup my ipod because I have more than 5gb and don't want to pay more. I would love to just put my camera roll on backup, and I deleted the backup for everything else but it still says I have too much gb on it! All I want is my camera roll!

Answer (score 1):

If the size of your camera roll is bigger than the available 5.0GB of space then you won't be able to back up to icloud unless you delete some of the content in your camera roll. Make sure by going into Settings>iCloud>Storage and Backup>Manage Storage that email, and other documents and data aren't using up any space. You can press edit and delete those if you don't need them.